# Criar user mysql em trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

preciso que após ser cadastrado um nova pessoa na tabela a trigger seja dispara e crie um novo usuário na base com os dados nome e senha do registro cadastrado. Tentei com vários modelos de insruções mas não obtive sucesso, tentei da maneira comum para se criar um novo usuário:

```
delimiter $
create trigger tgr_new_user after insert on pessoa
for each row
begin
    create user new.nome@'localhost' identified by new.senha;
end $
delimiter ;
```

porém o MySQL retorna erro.

Comment: *"porém o MySQL retorna erro"* qual erro? coloque na pergunta os detalhes

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível executar alguns comandos como `CREATE USER` dentro de uma trigger.
Aqui tem uma lista (em inglês) de alguma restrições: [stored-program-restrictions.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

Para criar um novo usuário vai precisar inserir diretamente na tabela de usuários do `MySQL`, que é a tabela  `mysql.user`:  [mysqluser-table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqluser-table/)

O comando ficaria por exemplo assim:

```
INSERT INTO mysql.user (host, user, password)
VALUES ('localhost',new.nome, new.senha);
```

Comment: Neste caso ele cria a trigger, mas ao inserir um novo cadastro na entidade ele da erro na execução da trigger "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
Estou utilizando MySQL 8